# How to set and out imaginary numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to show the roots of a quadratic equation, which usually are imaginary numbers. I am wondering how can I produce two roots and what to do in the case of an imaginary root. Here is what I have done so far. (first time using this site so I am not too familiar with etiquette and the tools yet so forgive me if my post is weird)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
    {
      int a, b, c, d;
      float x1, x2;
      cout << "Please input values for a, b and c to represent the variables in equation : ax^2 + bx + c" << endl; // Dont know how to raise 2 instead of using ^2
      cin >> a >> b >> c;
      d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
      cout << d << endl;
      cout << (-b + sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output? Also please double check the title. "Set and out?" Do you mean set and print?

Comment: What's actually wrong with simply using [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)? Just saying, because you're already `#include`ing it?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `#include <complex>` you are just telling the compiler to include a type template that is part of the standard library that implements complex arithmetic. You then need to actually instantiate the template and use that type for it to do anything for you.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a, b, c, det, root_1, root_2;
    std::cout << "Please input values for a, b and c to represent the variables in equation : ax^2 + bx + c\n"; /
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    det = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    root_1 = (-b + std::sqrt(det)) / (2.0 * a);
    root_2 = (-b - std::sqrt(det)) / (2.0 * a);

    std::cout << root_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << root_2 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers represent a useful enrichment of the C ++ language, which has entered the ISO 98 standard
C ++ language. The complex type belongs to the so-called derived types and is represented by the word
"Complex". As this type is not built into the C ++ kernel itself but is defined in the standard library
language C ++, for its use it is necessary to include in the program a library header which is also
called “complex”. In mathematics, a complex number is formally defined as a pair of real numbers, but how
in C ++ we have several types for describing real numbers ("float", "double" and "long double"),
complex numbers can be derived from each of these types. Syntax for declaring complex
it is variable

```
complex <basic_type> list_of variables;
```

where base_type is the type from which we derive the complex type. For example, a declaration of form

```
complex <double> z;
```

we declare a complex variable “z” of which the real and imaginary parts are of the “double” type. Complex
types can even be derived from one of integer types. For example,

```
complex <int> gauss;
```

declares a complex variable "gauss" whose real and imaginary numbers can only be integers
values ​​of type “int”. Otherwise, complex numbers of which the real and imaginary part are integers have large ones
significance in number theory and algebra, where Gaussian integers are called (this was the motivation for this
we call the variable “gauss”).
Like all other variables, complex variables can be initialized on occasion
declarations. Complex variables are typically initialized by a pair of values ​​in parentheses, which
represent the real or imaginary part of the number. For example, a declaration

```
complex <double> z1 (2, 3.5);
```

Also, when performing all arithmetic operations, it is allowed to mix operands of complex type i
of an integer or real type, it being preferred that the corresponding real type be the same type from which
is performed the appropriate complex type (otherwise, in certain situations there may be problems with
by mixing types, to which the compiler will warn us). Therefore, if they are, in addition to the above
variables, declared and real variables “x” and “y”, as well as integer variables “p” and “q”,
Expressions such as the following are also legal:

```
 a + b * y
  a * real (c) - b * imag (c)
p + c - complex <double> (x + y, x - y)
(a + b / x) * (c - complex <double> (p, q)) / p
```

We need to beware of expressions like

```
 a + (3.2, 2.15)
```

which, although syntactically correct, do not do what the user might expect, given already
mention the treatment of the expression of the form “(x, y)”.